# Как в C++ удалить экземпляр класса?

Tags: c++, классы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int a;
        A()
        {
            a=2;
        }
        ~A()
        {
            a=1;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A * aa = new A();
    delete aa;
    if (aa)
    cout<< aa->a;
    else
    cout<<"123";
}
```

Создаю указатель на экземпляр класса, вызываю конструктор, переменная "a" содержит число 2. Вызываю деструктор (в котором это "a" должно стать равным 1). Сначала ставлю проверку, существует ли указатель на экземпляр класса. Оказалось, что мало того, что он существует после деструктора, так ещё и в "a" лежит число 0. Выходит, в памяти начинают лежать ноли, но она всё ещё занята программой?
Как удалить из памяти весь экземпляр класса? Если я заменю ссылку на класс (в данном случае "aa") на отсутствующую, то (по логике) память это не освободит, а лишь не даст мне больше управлять этой памятью по этой ссылке.

Comment: Стандартное заблуждение, что после `delete` переменная-указатель должна обнуляться... Интересно, откуда у нее "ноги растут"?

Comment: @Harry Полагаю, из обычной человеческой логики. Удаляя ты хочешь удалить. Но вопрос не в этом. Из памяти экземпляр класса действительно удалён после delete или просто все его ячейки памяти принимают значение 0?

Comment: Он именно удален, а что его ячейки принимают какое-то значение - так об этом в стандарте ничего не говорится...

Comment: @Глеб: Что означает фраза "ставлю проверку, существует ли указатель на экземпляр класса". Почему вы решили, что эта проверка проверяет "существует ли указатель"? `delete aa` только удалило объект, на который указатель указывал. `delete aa` ничего не делает с самим указателем. Указатель у вас - локальная переменная. Он будет существовать до конца блока.

Comment: @AnT я решил, что delete (как следует из перевода слова) именно удаляет, и что будет не только освобождена память, но и указатель станет указывать на NULL (ведь delete применяемо именно к указателю). В таком случае if от указателя равного NULL вернул бы false. Это и есть суть проверки, оказалось, что в указателе лежал не NULL. В lua удаление таблицы и затем проверка указателя на таблицу возвращала false, вот и заинтересовало, как дела в плюсах, почему адрес не NULL, и как тогда освобождать память.

Comment: @Глеб Во-первых, на один и тот же объект может указывать 100 указателей. `delete` мог бы иметь возможность поставить один из них в null. Но это бы ничего не дало, ибо остальные указатели не станут null. Во-вторых, формально `delete` вообще принимает на вход *значение*, а не *переменную*. Например, возможно `delete ptr - 25`. То есть `delete` в принципе не может поменять передаваемый в него указатель. У него нет доступа к самой переменной-указателю.

Comment: @AnT по поводу сотни других указателей: фунция delete принимает аргументом конкретный указатель, его и могла бы обнулить. Будь у меня сотня указателей, но только один указан в delete, я бы ожидал, что другие 99 будут указывать на мусор, ведь они не были аргументами delete. По поводу аргумента delete: товарищ ниже уже пояснил, что принимается не сам указатель, а копия. Был указатель 0x00000001, а будет отправлено число 1.

Comment: @Глеб Это прекрасно. Но в языке С++ сделано именно так. И это снова возвращает нас к вопросу "почему вы решили...". Судить по функциональности оператора С++ по переводу слова из словаря - бесперспективное занятие. `delete` действительно "удаляет". Но вот обнуление указателя в это "удаление" не включается.

Comment: @AnT люди делают вещи для людей. Ожидаемо, что человеческая логика будет работать. И что если один раз мне показали, что p=10 отправит в переменную p значение 10, то в другом месте эта запись не должна создать 10 экземпляров класса p, например, и не должна создать переменную из 10 букв p в названии со значением 0. Для другого функционала должна быть другая запись. -- это про "возвращение к вопросу", к текущему уже не относится. Когда логика нарушена, тогда и возникает очевидный вопрос "почему?/с какой целью?"

Comment: @Глеб Абстрактная человеческая логика может/должна работать на уровне "обзора с высоты птичьего полета", big picture. Когда же речь заходит о технических деталях - надо читать документацию. Да, `p = 10` присваивает `p` значение 10 - это человеческая  логика. А вот что при этом происходит с padding bits в `p`, или что происходит если 10 не помещается в `p` - это уже детали, которые из абстрактной человеческой логики извлечь не получится.

Comment: @Глеб Есть в С++ такой принцип, *"you don't pay for what you don't use"*. Установить указатель в ноль - медленнее, чем не устанавливать. Если бы delete обнулял указатель всегда, даже когда программисту это не нужно, принцип бы нарушался.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[[basic.stc]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4)**
>
> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values. **Indirection through an invalid pointer value** and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function **have undefined behavior.** **Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

После `delete aa;`, указатель `aa` становится невалидным, и поведение `if (aa)` зависит от компилятора.

Что более важно, следующая строка - `aa->a` - вызывает неопределенное поведение, из-за доступа через невалидный указатель.

Раз поведение не определено, смысла рассуждать, почему вы видите в консоли `0` или что-то еще - немного.

---

> Сначала ставлю проверку, существует ли указатель на экземпляр класса.

`delete` не обнуляет указатель. Так что проверка - не работает.

> мало того, что он существует после деструктора

Он не "существует". Объект перестает существовать после вызова на нем деструктора<sup>1</sup>.

Вот только в языке нет способа проверить, указывает указатель на "существующий" объект, или нет.

> так ещё и в "a" лежит число 0

`a` - тоже не существует. Читать из него - неопределенное поведение.

> Выходит, в памяти начинают лежать ноли, но она всё ещё занята программой? Как удалить из памяти весь экземпляр класса?

Что значит "удалить из памяти"? Память - это набор байт. Вы можете поменять значения байт, в которых находился объект, на какие-то другие, и все. Эти байты нельзя "удалить".

---

<sup>1</sup> Точнее, [нетривиального](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.3) деструктора, но здесь это не важно.

Comment: `Что значит "удалить из памяти"?` имелась ввиду та память, которая выделена под нужды этой программы. В данном случае я имел ввиду "освободить для других программ".

Comment: Присваивайте nullptr элементу после удаления, и вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Comment: @Глеб Память выдается программе и освобождается не под каждый объект отдельно а более крупными кусками. Пример: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d888040e21f4088

Answer (score 2):

После

```
delete aa;
```

значение указателя, хранящегося в переменной `aa` **не изменяется**.

А указывает она на уже освобожденный блок памяти, который может остаться в том же состоянии, быть перезаписанным - в общем, с ним может произойти что угодно (на то и Undefined Behaviour). В любом случае вы не должны к нему обращаться - ни к чему хорошему это привести не может.

Comment: значение указателя, хранящегося в переменной aa не изменяется.? Или оно может меняться на другое, но в любом случаи не на ноль, а может не меняться?....

Comment: Оператор delete применяется к указателю. Так каков вселенский смысл оставлять этот указатель ссылаться на не принадлежащий больше программе участок памяти? По логике delete ptr; должно вызывать `delete ptr; ptr = NULL;` Лично я не вижу смысл оставлять его, если память действительно больше не принадлежит программе.

Comment: @Глеб Значение указателя не меняется, так как он передается оператору-функции delete по значению. То есть оператор-функция delete имеет дело с копией значения исходного указателя.

Comment: Какраз этот оператор применяется для удаления обьекта, чей адрес хранит указатель,  А значение указателья может и меняться по ходу программы, если распределитель решит этот кусок памяти использовать...

Comment: *По логике delete ptr; должно вызывать delete ptr; ptr = NULL;"* По вашей логике, `delete ptr+2;` (удаление третьего элемента в массиве, например) должно приводить к `ptr+2 = NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Программа имеет неопределенное поведение, так как после удаления объекта класса

```
delete aa;
```

значение указателя `aa` становится невалидным. То есть указатель не указывает на существующий "живой" объект в программе.

Имейте в виду, что при вызове оператора-функции `delete` или `delete[]` значение указателя не меняется. так как указатель передается в оператор-функцию по значению, то есть оператор-функция имеет дело с копией значения исходного указателя.

Это означает, что проверка в `if-предложении` даст истину

```
if (aa)
    cout<< aa->a
```

То есть `aa` - это не `null-указатель`,

Однако обращение к члену уже не существующего объекта

```
    cout<< aa->a
```

приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: "... значение указателя не меняется" - это формально неверно.  Такой указатель снова приобретает indeterminate value, т.е. его значение становится непредсказуемым и, возможно, нестабильным. Утверждение, что оно "не меняется" - слишком сильное. Да, `delete` не может его поменять прямо, но косвенно оно "меняется".

Comment: @AnT В данном контексте indeterminate value имеет значение того, что указатель не указывает на реальный объект, а не то, что его значение изменилось. То есть меняется статус значения указателя, а не само значение.

Comment: Нет. Тема эта много обсуждалась и в С, и в С++. Практический аспект этого вопроса: если значение `aa` было временно поднято из памяти в регистр процессора, то нужно ли по завершении работы с `aa` (то есть после `delete aa;`) делать register spill, т.е. сбрасывать последнее (indeterminate) значение регистра обратно в память? Ответ - не нужно. Именно ради таких оптимизацией идея indeterminate value и существует в С и С++. Из-за того, что последнее (регистровое) значение `aa` может быть не сброшено в память, запросто может получиться эффект того, что значение `aa` "поменялось" после `delete aa;`.

Answer (score 0):

Немного увеличим программу, тогда будет понятней:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A(int k = 2) : a(k) {}
    ~A() {  a=1; }
};
```

программа:

```
A * aa = new A();
delete aa;
if (aa)
    cout<< aa->a << '\t' << aa << endl;
//
else
    cout<<"123" << endl;
A* bb = new A(1245);
// может использоваться память содержащайся в аа а может и нет
cout << bb << '\t' << bb->a << endl;

// теперь хотим использовать и обьявленный b и адрес хранящийся в аа
// размещаем в аа новый обьект
bb = new(aa) A();
//теперь оба указателья содержат один и тот же адрес
cout << aa << '\t' << bb << endl
     << aa->a  <<'\t' << bb->a;
```

Компилятор не знает, что захочет сделать с выделенной памятью программист(или не захочет). Поэтому  и `не нужно`, как говорится выше `проверить, указывает указатель на "существующий" объект, или нет, не только потому что нет в языке такого способа.`